# What is the difference between Scrum and Extreme Programming?

Tags: agile, scrum, methodology, extreme-programming

A few years ago I have worked on a green field project where we did Extreme Programming. I also see a lot of people mention the Scrum methodology.

Could someone tell me the main differences between Scrum and XP?

Comment: So, what was the answer? When I see in job vacancies SCRUM should I understand that it is telling AGILE with regular short meetings or what?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Scrum is a software development methodology, XP is a programming practice. Both are "agile" techniques and are often used together.

Scrum outlines a process for identifying and cataloging work that needs to be done, prioritizing that work by communicating with the customer or customer representative, and implementing that work using iterative releases.

When my team first started experimenting with Scrum I found the [Implementing Scrum](http://www.implementingscrum.com/) website to be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Scrum is lightweight framework for building a product where there is high levels of complexity and uncertainty.  It is NOT a methodology, as methodologies and practices can be chosen and used in conjunction to Scrum.  It is not purely aimed at software development and can be used by other types of projects too.

When it comes to software engineering, Scrum does not define what practices to follow or methods follow as it does not want to prescribe what is best for that particular product and environment.

Many Scrum teams use several XP practices such as Testing, Feedback, Pair Programming and Simplicity.

The core differences

- Scrum plans for a sprint and does not encourage change. XP is more open to change.
- XP solicits feedback immediately and Scrum at least at the Sprint Review,  however Scrum does not reject early feedback if possible.
- XP focuses on programming,  Scrum can be used in non software products
- Scrum does not define how to do development,  but many Scrum teams implement many of the XP practices

Answer (score 2):

I've worked on both.  Some of the main differences are that SCRUM focuses on the shorter more structured sprints, and prioritizes back log items.  Some of the focuses of XP are more on paired programming, prioritizing the tasks, and more test driven development.  Both work in iterations and both are flexible enough to handle a volatile changing project.

Answer (score 1):

Scrum is one component of the Agile development methodology concerning the daily meeting held to discuss progress and XP is a different methodology stressing pair programming and test first development.

Answer (score 0):

Scrum's main goal is to get estimations of how long development will take. XP is more about helping developers get things done as quickly and maintainably as possible.